# C++: как задать размерность двумерного вектора в конструкторе класса

Tags: c++, ооп, матрицы, конструктор, вектор

```
Class Matrix
{
        int dimension;
        vector<vector<int>> matrix;
    public:
        Matrix(int dimension);
        ...
}

Matrix::Matrix(int dimension)
{
    this->dimension = dimension;
}
```

В методе   `Matrix::Matrix(int dimension)` хочется задать размерность двумерного вектора

```
dimension x dimension
```

но тот способ, которым делал это я, не работает

```
matrix.reserve(dimension);
for (int i = 0; i < dimension; ++i)
{
     matrix[i].reserve(dimension);
}
```

Comment: 1. Используйте vector<int> для всех элементов массива, а не вектор векторов, так быстрее будет работать и надежнее.
2. Лучше всего template <int X, int Y>, а внутри int _matrix[X*Y], это самый быстрый вариант для всех операций.

Comment: @Arkady если размерности фиксируются на момент создания, `std::vector` вообще не нужен. Имхо, самым подходящим из стандартных тут будет `std::valarray`.

Comment: Да, обычно или матрица неясного размера (тогда пункт 1), или классические 3х3 2х2 1х3 и т.п., и их проще делать шаблонными, используя C-массивы (пункт 2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vector::reserve` только резервирует память под элементы, но не выделяет их.

Используйте `vector::resize`:

```
Matrix::Matrix(int dimension)
  : dimension(dimension),
    matrix(dimension)
{
    for (auto& row : matrix)
    {
        row.resize(dimension);
    }
}
```